# Should we use statement form in statements, even when talking about questions?

Tags: grammar, questions

Should we use statement form even when talking about questions?

For example:
Is it:

One can ask why we would believe that.

Or:

One can ask why would we believe that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both forms are possible here.  In normal prose you would use the the embedded interogative statement "why we would..."

But it also possible to treat this as a direct quote

> One can ask, "Why would we believe that?"

Comment: But only the first one is correct without quotation marks, right?

Comment: Please answer that ☝, since my whole question hinges on that.